# Typesafe Config does not take System properties that were set in runtime

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

I have a core library that sets its configuration as system properties.

```
mail.from = mail@example.com
```

I wanted to override my config with them, like:

```
my.mail.from = "me@example.com"
my.mail.from = ${?mail.from}
```

This works in unit tests. In my Play (2.6) application it does not.

```
PropertiesConfiguration.init() // this inits the system properties
info("mail.from: " + sys.props.get("mail.from")) // >> 'mail@example.com' as expected   
val config = ConfigFactory.load()
info("my.mail.from: " + config.getString("my.mail.from")) // >> 'me@example.com' instead of 'mail@example.com'
```

Is this not possible or do I miss something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try invalidating any cached configurations in order to pick up changes to system properties:

```
PropertiesConfiguration.init()
info("mail.from: " + sys.props.get("mail.from"))

ConfigFactory.invalidateCaches()

val config = ConfigFactory.load()
info("my.mail.from: " + config.getString("my.mail.from"))
```